# Python: как конвертировать строку в PIL изображение

Tags: python, изображения

Как в python конвертировать строку, а именно PNG загруженный в строку через `read()` метод `file`? При этом в строке просто содержимое файла, а не то, что получается при `tostring`. Как сделать это не сохраняя строку как файл?

Comment: Два раза перечитал, но так и не смог понять, чего же вы всё-таки хотите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, есть строка с содержимым PNG файла. Нужно не сохраняя снова в png открыть как PIL изображения. PIL требует файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

# Получение строки
img_data = None
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as fh:
    img_data = fh.read()

# Создание PIL.Image на основе строки
with BytesIO(img_data) as img_buf:
    with Image.open(img_buf) as img:
        img.show()
```